# insert value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

im new in PHP. just a simple question :

Coding :

```
foreach($group as $b)
{
  if($b == 0){
       echo "error";
  }
  else{
        echo "true";
  }
}
```

i want value $b that "true" add to new array.

thanks.

Comment: To which array? Create some right before `foreach`

Comment: Use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
foreach($group as $b) {
    if ($b == 0) {
        echo "error";
    } else {
        echo "true";
        $arr[] = $b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
array_push($array, "true");
```

Comment: i want to add value $b into array.

array_push($new_array, $b);

am i right?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Define the array.**
2. **Push the data** into the array.

Example:

```
$array = new array();

foreach ($group as $b) {
    if ($b == 0) {
       echo "error";
    } else {
    echo "true";
    array_push($array,$b) //or any value?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) check this link

```
 $a = new array();
array_push($a,"true");
print_r($a);
```

We can add to a numerical array in these ways:

```
$arr = new array("true");    //Create the array & add the values
var_dump($arr);    //Print the contents of the array to screen
```

You can also push values to an array:

```
$arr = new array();    //Create the array
array_push($arr, 'true');    //'Push' the value into the next available index
var_dump($arr);    //Print the contents of the array to screen
```

You can also add to array by directly setting the index:

```
$arr = new array();    //Create the array
$arr[0] = 'true';    //'Set' index 0 to the value
var_dump($arr);    //Print the contents of the array to screen
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it:

```
array_push($arr,"true");
```

or

```
echo "true";
$arr[] = $b;
```

To know more about array_push read this :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Use `$arr[]` instead of `array_push()` - it's faster.